# How can I scale a font in fontspec without changing the font?

Tags: fontspec, fontsize, scale

I am trying to change the default font size in my document. I am using the `fontspec` package in XeLaTeX. This seems achievable using `\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=2.5}`, but this only takes effect after I add a `\setmainfont{...}` command. The problem is that I do not want to change the main font. How do I get the font to scale without explicitly selecting a font? The funny thing is that the math mode part of my document shows up as scaled even though the regular text doesn't. I'm assuming the `unicode-math` package must be selecting a font after this, but it's not explicit. Any advice on this would be VERY appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=2.5}
\linespread{3}
%\setmainfont{...} %%Putting the name of a font in this command makes it do what I want, but I don't want to specify a font.

\begin{document}

A physical dipole has a separation $\symbf{d}$ between two charges $\pm q$ and a dipole moment $\symbf{p}$:
$$\symbf{p}\equiv q\symbf{d}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but using `$$` to delimit displayed equations is not recommended. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/

Comment: The default fonts are loaded together with `fontspec`, so they aren't subject to subsequent `\declarefontfeatures` declarations.

Answer (score 1):

`\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{42}{46}\selectfont}` in the preamble yields:[image]

Which hopefully is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is precisely what you want, but the `Koma-Script` classes allow to choose whatever (absolute) size of fonts you prefer thanks to their `fontsize` class parameter. E.g., for their `scrartcl` class (equivalent to the usual `article` class):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=25pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=2.5}
\linespread{3}
%\setmainfont{...} %%Putting the name of a font in this command makes it do what I want, but I don't want to specify a font.

\begin{document}

A physical dipole has a separation $\symbf{d}$ between two charges $\pm q$ and a dipole moment $\symbf{p}$:
\[\symbf{p}\equiv q\symbf{d}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This gives the desired effect, but the `scrartcl` class introduces some undesired behavior in the rest of my document (like sans serif fonts in section titles). I'm sure there are ways to fix these, too, but I was hoping there would be a solution using `article`.

Answer (score 0):

One method of general applicability (does not involve math) is to use `setmainfont` in a way that does not change anything. It seems that `\setmainfont` sets some kind of flag, which needs to be seen by `\addfontfeatures`. The following MWE works in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. It uses `\setmainfont` to echo whatever your default font actually is, at that point; if you didn't choose one, it echoes Latin Modern Roman, the standard default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=2.5}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\rmdefault}{lmr}}{
    \setmainfont{lmroman12-regular.otf} % can be improved
  }{}
\else
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\rmdefault}{lmr}}{
    \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
  }{}
\fi
\begin{document}
Hello!\par
\rmdefault
\end{document}
```

LuaLaTeX can find Latin Modern Roman by font family name, but in many cases XeLaTeX can only find it by font file name. The line marked "can be improved" is where you would add the font file names for bold and italics, as `fontspec` options to the main font.